# Sentence construction

Tags: sentence-meaning

i want to ask my fellow passenger if my destination will come then please wake me up. Let me know if below sentences are correct.

> Let me know when my stop is come ( if bus has reached stop) Or 
>   Let me know when my stop will come ( if bus is about to reached the stop) Or 
>   Let me know when my stop has come.( if bus has already reached my stop) Or 
>   Let me know when my stop come ( Simple tense)

Answer (score 1):

The fourth one seems better.

> Let me know when my stop comes (note - comes)

The subtle difference I find is...

*is come* = *has come* but the former one is biblical ([He is come](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13222/he-is-come-john-168)) construction.

*will come* does not work as good as *comes* because you are asking them to *let you know* when the stop actually **comes**.

The simple present tense works here as things are pretty sure to happen.

Answer (score 1):

> (if bus has reached stop) Let me know when we *arrive at* my stop.
>
> (if bus is about to reached the stop) Let me know when we *get close to* my stop.

I think to put the verb before "my stop" makes for a more understandable sentence. In another example of similar form to one of your examples:

> Let me know when my *sister* will come.

Here "my sister" is moving, but in your example "my stop" is not moving, you are. Not that it would be misunderstood, though

Then consider the best verb based on the situation.