# "are come" or "have come" correct use

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, deverbal

I read some sentences which used "all are come". Is this correct formation?

Consider the following examples:

> a) "All are come to office today" (Meaning Status)
>
> b) "All have come to office today" (Meaning completed Action)

In the above example I feel sentence b) is correct.However If *he is gone* and *they are gone* are correct then can we use *He is come* and *they are come* in English?

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: "Are come" is an older form. Contemporary English speakers say "have come" (as this ngram attests: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(are+come)%2C(have+come)&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28are%20come%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28have%20come%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @TRomano: I've noticed that you answer a lot of questions in comments. I think it would be better if you posted your answers as answers, so that they can be upvoted (so the questions are no longer "unanswered"), accepted, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [He IS come - John 16:8](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13222/he-is-come-john-168)

Comment: It does seem like a duplicate but the answer by StoneyB is more detailed than the one in the older post. It would be a shame to lose this one IMO

Answer (score 4):

*BE come* on the analogy of *BE gone* is a good guess, and in fact in older English it was usual to use *BE* rather than *HAVE* to form the perfects of verbs of motion; but this is no longer idiomatic in Present-Day English.

*Gone* in "He's gone now" is what is sometimes called a *deverbal*: a participle that has been recategorized as an adjective. Some others are

- done
- excited *and* exciting
- experiencing
- finished
- interested *and* interesting
- surprised *and* surprising

You pretty much have to learn one by one which participles can be used as adjectives, and in what contexts: some can be used as predicate complements, some as attributives before the noun modified, some can be used both ways.

Comment: Probably useful to mention that "I am excited" and "I have excited" are different unlike "I am done" and "I have done".  I realize you're not pulling that comparison *on purpose*, but you placed those together in the list...

Comment: @VictorBazarov To tell the truth, intransitive *HAS done* never occurred to me; it has practically disappeared from AmE, and my impression is that it survives in BrE mostly as an extended 'Code'.