# why is this sentence wrong "it was happened yesterday"

Tags: grammar

I am not exactly sure why this sentence wrong? I think it's supposed to be "it happened yesterday"

Comment: In English the **present perfect** is always constructed using the auxiliary *have*  never *be* unlike many languages where both auxiliaries are used. The clause "he **is gone**" used to be common in English over a 150 years ago  but today we say "he **has gone**". In your example, only the simple past **it happened** *YESTERDAY* is acceptable. If there was no definite time expression it would be **it has happened**.

Comment: Also related: [He IS come--John 16:8](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13222/he-is-come-john-168)

Comment: An excellent answer posted by an ELU user that helps to understand "why"... https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3415/44619

Answer (score 0):

*Happened* is a past tense verb and past participle. It is not an adjective, so it can't be linked to *it* by the copulative verb *is*.

Some past participles can be used as adjectives, for example, *It is done.*, but *happened* isn't used that way.